# Python webscraper to get property info from Tripadvisor

Tags: python, performance, beginner, excel, web-scraping

I'm very much a beginner at programming, and hoping to get some advice!
I'm having some trouble with a tripadvisor scraper being slow, and have identified the part of my code that is taking a while. It's likely because of the long selector, but i'm not sure how to use anything more specific because there are randomly generated strings on the more specific selectors. Below the snippet that is taking a while, and below that is the full code. Would appreciate any feedback!

Sample of the webpages im scraping:

https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotels-g255100-Melbourne_Victoria-Hotels.html

https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotel_Review-g255100-d257433-Reviews-The_Hotel_Windsor-Melbourne_Victoria.html

Code giving me problems:

```
        num_rooms = 0
        extra_info = soup.select('#taplc_about_addendum_react_0 div div div div')
        for data in extra_info:
            data = data.text.strip()
            if data.isdigit():
                num_rooms = int(data)
```

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter
import time


def get_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


def write_xlsx(items, xlsx_write_row):
    write_column = 0
    for item in items:
        worksheet.write(xlsx_write_row, write_column, item)
        write_column += 1


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Results.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


# user variables
while True:
    start_url = input('Start url: ')
    if 'https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotels-' not in start_url:
        print(
            'Please enter a valid url. e.g https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotels-g255100-Melbourne_Victoria-Hotels.html')
    else:
        break

print('fetching page...')
soup = get_soup(start_url)

while True:
    min_rev_num = input('Min Reviews for property: ')
    if min_rev_num.isdigit():
        if int(min_rev_num) >= 0:
            min_rev_num = int(min_rev_num)
            break
    print('Please enter a valid number')

while True:
    print('Enter max number of low review number properties on a single page, from 0 to 30.')
    print('(Program will exit once this condition is fulfilled)')
    num_rev_criteria = input('Input: ')
    if num_rev_criteria.isdigit():
        if 0 <= int(num_rev_criteria) <= 30:
            num_rev_criteria = int(num_rev_criteria)
            break

    print('Please enter a valid number')

while True:
    min_star_rating = input('Min star rating for property: ')
    if min_star_rating.isdigit():
        if 0 <= int(min_star_rating) <= 5:
            min_star_rating = float(min_star_rating)
            break

    print('Please enter a valid number')

while True:
    min_room_num = input('Min number of rooms: ')
    if min_room_num.isdigit():
        if int(min_room_num) >= 0:
            min_room_num = int(min_room_num)
            break
    print('Please enter a valid number')

while True:
    max_num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.pageNum.last.taLnk').text.strip())
    num_pages = input('Page to search until(1 to {}):'.format(str(max_num_pages)))
    if num_pages.isdigit():
        if 1 <= int(num_pages) <= max_num_pages:
            num_pages = int(num_pages)
            break
    print('Please enter a valid number')
print('-'*30 + '\n')
check = input("Make sure 'Results.xlsx' is closed and deleted. Once you are ready, press enter")

write_row = 0
write_xlsx(['Property Details', 'Star Rating', 'Number of Rooms'], write_row)
page_url = start_url
rejected_properties = 0

start = time.time()
print('Getting data...')

# get property data
for page_num in range(num_pages):
    print('\nOn page {}\n'.format(str(page_num + 1)))
    low_review_count = 0
    soup = get_soup(page_url)
    if page_num != num_pages - 1:
        next_page = soup.select_one('.nav.next.taLnk.ui_button.primary')['href']
        page_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg' + next_page
    else:
        pass
    rows = soup.select('.property_title.prominent')
    prop_urls = []
    for row in rows:
        prop_urls.append('https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg' + row['href'])
    for prop in prop_urls:
        soup = get_soup(prop)
        try:
            num_reviews = int(soup.select_one('.reviewCount').text.strip().split(' ')[0].replace(',', ''))
        except AttributeError:
            num_reviews = 0

        try:
            property_name = soup.select_one('#HEADING').text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            property_name = ' '

        if num_reviews >= min_rev_num:

            try:
                star_rating_class = soup.select_one('.ui_star_rating')['class'][1]
                star_rating = float(star_rating_class[5] + '.' + star_rating_class[6])
            except TypeError:
                star_rating = 0

            num_rooms = 0
            extra_info = soup.select('#taplc_about_addendum_react_0 div div div div')
            for data in extra_info:
                data = data.text.strip()
                if data.isdigit():
                    num_rooms = int(data)

            try:
                address = soup.select_one('.street-address').text.strip() + ', ' + soup.select_one('.locality').text.strip() + soup.select_one('.country-name').text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                address = ' '

            try:
                phone = soup.select_one('.is-hidden-mobile.detail').text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                phone = ' '

            if star_rating >= min_star_rating or star_rating == 0:
                if num_rooms >= min_room_num or num_rooms == 0:
                    write_row += 1
                    write_xlsx([property_name + '\n' + address + '\nT: ' + phone, star_rating, num_rooms], write_row)
                else:
                    print("Rejected: '{}'\n".format(property_name) + ' - Not enough rooms:{}'.format(num_rooms))
            else:
                print("Rejected: '{}'\n".format(property_name)+' - Not high enough star rating:{}'.format(star_rating))
        else:
            low_review_count += 1
            print("Rejected: '{}'\n".format(property_name) + ' - Not enough reviews:{}'.format(num_reviews))
            print(' - Low review count: {}/{}'.format(low_review_count, num_rev_criteria))

    if low_review_count >= num_rev_criteria:
        print('Exiting due to low review count on page')
        break

workbook.close()
end = time.time()

print("\nDone! Results can be found in 'Results.xlsx' in the same folder\n")
print('Results can be copied straight onto the shortlist(paste values only), formatting has already been done.')
print('If any results have 0 stars or 0 rooms, Tripadvisor does not have this data')
print('Address and phone numbers are based on Tripadvisor data as well\n')
print('Number of pages searched: {}'.format(str(page_num + 1)))
props_searched = (page_num - 1)*30 + len(prop_urls)
print('Number of properties searched: {}'.format(str(props_searched)))
print('Number of properties accepted: {}'.format(str(write_row - 1)))
print('Number of properties rejected: {}'.format(str(props_searched - write_row + 1)))
print('Time taken: {} minutes'.format(str((end-start)//60)))
while True:
    check = input('\nTo exit, press enter')
    if True:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on the `.com` version of the site (I can't access the `.com.sg`) the content your looking for is:

```
<div class="hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__title--2QuyD">NUMBER OF ROOMS</div>
<div class="hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__content--iVts5">180</div>
```

This appears to be consistent across pages. So, you could look for a `.hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__title--2QuyD` followed by a `.hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__content--iVts5`. You probably want to check that the text in the first div is `NUMBER OF ROOMS` in case some pages have more "addendum items" with purely numeric content:

When scraping, I like pulling things out into functions to make my intent more clear, to make testing easier, and to make it easier to refactor if (more likely, when the page changes):

```
def get_addendum_item_titles(page):
    return page.find_all('div', class_='.hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__title--2QuyD')

def get_number_of_rooms_addendum_title(page):
    for title in get_addendum_item_titles(page):
        if title.text.strip().upper() == 'NUMBER OF ROOMS':
            return title

    raise ValueError('Number of rooms addendum title not found')

def get_number_of_rooms(page):
    title = get_number_of_rooms_addendum_title(page)
    content = title.parent.find('div', class_='.hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__content--iVts5')
    return int(content.text.strip())
```

You may want to throw those class names in constants.

A prime justification for this approach is immediately obvious. The `--2QuyD`-like suffixes are almost certainly automatically generated. I suspect the next time tripadvisor modifies any of their CSS these suffixes will change and break your code. But I imagine that the `hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__title` part will rarely change. So you need a way of finding the proper classname with only that prefix. Ideally you create a function like:

```
def find_class_with_prefix(page, prefix):
    pass
```

I'll leave that as an exercise to you, but once you create it, it will be really cleanly integratable into the above code.

Note there is a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax) that you can use instead for this: `div[class^=hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__title]`, but I suspect it will have poor performance characteristics because it probably uses a linear scan. You'll want to tap into whatever datastructures beautifulsoup already has built for quickly looking up elements by class (to find the list of class names).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response, it was exactly what i was looking for! I was considering even using some string methods to search the raw html out of desperation. Some parts of your answer are still a bit beyond me, but i'll research and make sense of it. At least I have a sense of what to do now. Will look into make the function to find the prefix if it changes as well. Thank you so much!